# Definition of exponent measure (extreme value theory)

Tags: extreme-value, definition, measure-theory

Let $F$ be a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $U_i$ be the left continuous inverse of $\frac{1}{1-F_i}$, where $F_i$ is the marginal distribution of $F$.

In my textbook, there is the following definition.

$H(x,y) = 1- \frac{1-F(U_1(nx), U_2(ny))}{1-F(U_1(na), U_2(na))}$ for $\max (x,y) > a$, and this is supposed to be a distribution function.

However, say for $a = 2$, we can have $(1,3)$, and it's possible for $H(x,y) < 0$. (i.e. $\max (x,y) > a$ doesn't guarantee that $H(x,y) > 0$)

[image]

How do I reconcile that?

The book is Extreme Value Theory: An Introduction by Haan

Comment: What you assert is not possible because $F$ is a nonincreasing function in each variable.  It's a good idea to have some simple examples in mind when you read mathematics like this so you can understand what's going on.  Work it out for a uniform distribution $F,$ for instance.

Comment: @whuber but if $x<a$, $y>a$, isn't it possible to have $F(x,y) <F(a,a)$?

Comment: I misread it, probably as it was intended to be misread ;-).  Notice that the measure $P_{n,a}$ is said to be defined on $\mathbb R^2_+\setminus [0,a]^2,$ which means the author is assuming $a\lt x$ and $a\lt y:$ that is, $\min(x,y)\gt y.$

Comment: @whuber but say $a = 2$, then $(1,3) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+ \ [0,2]^2$ with $min(x,y)<2$.

Comment: Then I must be confused ;-).  I don't have the book to consult for greater context to try to understand the claim.